# Call to undefined method Test::component() in Laravel package testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I have a Laravel package that will provide UI components (in Blade) and I want to write some unit tests for these components. I am using PHPunit 10.4 and orchestra testbench 8.15.

Base testcase:

```
class TestCase extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
    /**
     * Get the array of package providers.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPackageProviders($app) : array
    {
        return [
            MyPackageServiceProvider::class
        ];
    }
}
```

Testcase for the component:

```php
class LabelComponentTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function test_label_component_renders_text(): void
    {
        $component = $this->component(Label::class, ['text' => 'Hello']);

        $component->assertSee('Hello');
    }
}
```

When I run my tests I get this error:

> Call to undefined method ... LabelComponentTest::component()

Why can I not use the `component()` method, the `blade()` method does not work either?

Comment: I have never tested a component, but I am looking at the documentation and I cannot find any `$this->component()` method available for test, where did you get that?

Comment: It is under http tests: [rendering blade and components](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#rendering-blade-and-components).

Comment: which `TestCase` is that? Could you share the full namespace? I am not exactly sure if you have everything with orchestra, I think you do, I am investigating

Comment: I think this is what you are missing: https://packages.tools/testbench/the-basic.html#testing-blade-components